# Using java validate a string is printed in particular format

Tags: java, regex

I have a response string like as follows

```
21.03.2019_15:06.26 [SELOGER]:: [Seloger value]-[PROGRESS]:  marminto=true, france24=true,
```

Using Java I have to validate the above response is printed in following format:

```
<date+time> [SELOGER]:: [Seloger value]-[<PROGRESS|STOP|START>]: <value1>=<true|false>, <value2>=<true|false>........
```

1. first is `<date+time>` then `[SELOGER]:: [Seloger value]-` then `[PROGRESS or STOP or START]:` then values `marminto=true, france24=true,.....`

How can i perform this with `regex`? or any java API's available to detect a string is printed in particular format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\_\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2} \[SELOGER\]:: \[Seloger value\]-\[(?:PROGRESS|STOP|START)\]: *(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+=(?:true|false), ?)*
```

Explanation:

`\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\_\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}` matches date in specified format

`(?:PROGRESS|STOP|START)` - conditional, match any from `PROGRESS`, `STOP` or `START`

`(?:[a-z0-9]+=(?:true|false), ?)*` - match zero or more `value=true`/`value=false`  pairs optionally followed by space and followed by comma

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AMueUX/2)

Comment: But when the response is :21.03.2019_15:06.26 [SELOGER]:: [Seloger value]-[PROGRESS]:  ZBAM=true, RRKWhiteList=true, it is not working

Comment: some times the <value1>=<true|false> the value key name contains special characters in that case how can i handle it?

Comment: @Psl Just modify `[a-zA-Z0-9]` part: between square brackets add any special characters that are acceptable, eg.: `[a-zA-Z0-9\$]` - here I added `$` and escaped it with `\`, as it's special character fo regex.

Comment: understood...rather than entering special chars one by one.like [a-zA-Z0-9\$\#\_\-].is there any way to mention all special characters using regex inside [a-zA-Z0-9]

Comment: sorry to disturb you again.. some times the respose will be : response is :21.03.2019_15:06.26 [SELOGER]:: [Seloger value]-[PROGRESS]: it will not contain value=true/false. in such case i put an or condition in the regex as follows...but it is not working..... \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\_\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2} \[SELOGER\]:: \[Seloger value\]-\[(?:PROGRESS|STOP|START)\]:?( {1,2}(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+=(?:true|false), ?)+)